# Creating an onAfter Event for Kwicks jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using [Kwicks jQuery plugin](http://www.jeremymartin.name/projects.php?project=kwicks) for my portfolio. I want to show a child container within the list item after the kwicks click event. I can't seem to find a hook for this, at least within the parameters of the kwicks plugin.

After doing some research I couldn't find anything. Anybody know how to achieve this?

I'm using jQuery 1.4.2 and Kwicks 1.5.1.

P.S. If you couldn't tell, I'm a total jQuery/javascript noob.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$().ready(function() {

 $('#projects').kwicks({
  max : 720,
  event : 'click'
 });


 $('.desc').show();
});

</script>


<ul id="projects">
    <li>
      <div class="desc">
      <h3><%= project.title %></h3>
      <p>blah blah blah<%= project.description %></p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="desc">
      <h3><%= project.title %></h3>
      <p>blah blah blah<%= project.description %></p>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: As a side note, `$().ready` is not a recommended format (ref: http://api.jquery.com/ready/) and my not be supported in future versions of jQuery

Comment: Also, just so you know, you got me inspired to update Kwicks... I've updated it to version 2.0 and added it to my github (https://github.com/Mottie/Kwicks). Check out the demo - http://mottie.github.com/Kwicks/

Comment: Nice fudgey! I had my code about 80% complete around the original version, but your version seems to have the hooks I need without modifying the plugin itself. I'll give it a go and let you know if I run into any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using fudgey's rewrite of the kwicks (http://github.com/Mottie/Kwicks) and it worked like a champ. This is what I ended up with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function hideAllDesc(){ // Fades out all descriptions that are shown before expanding a new one
    $('#projects li .desc').fadeOut();
  }

  function showDesc(){ // Shows description on expand
    $('#projects li.active .desc').fadeIn();
  }

  function hideDesc(){ // Hides description on collapse/mouseout
    $('#projects li.active .desc').fadeOut();
  }

  $('#projects').kwicks({
    max : 720,
    event : 'click',
    init : hideAllDesc,
    expanding : showDesc,    
    collapsing : hideDesc

  });

});
```

Thanks for your help everybody!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing it without patching Kwicks.

To patch it, in line 125 of the non-minified code after

```
easing: o.easing
```

add a comma and then:

```
complete: function()
{
    // your code
}
```

Or, to use a custom function every time:

```
complete: o.onAfter
```

Comment: Well, that's not entirely true. You probably could unbind the original event handler and wrap it in a function of yours, but before you do that you could rather do Kwick's work manually.

Comment: Thanks AndreKR this worked. I also had to add a function to hide the description on mouseleave. Seems a bit dirty doing it this way but it will work until I get more verse in jQuery/JS and refactor it.